# Why is there no output for this code and also how to reclaim memory?

Tags: c++, exception, memory, static, output

[This is the original lab question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNWqh.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

class c{
public:
    c(){
    int i = 0;

    vector <c*> objects;
    while (true){

        objects.push_back(new c());
        cout << "Object " << i+1 << "is created.";
        i++;

        if (i == 10) {
            throw i+1;}}}
};

int main(){

    while (true){
    try {c obj;}

    catch (int x) {cout << "Object" << x << "cannot be created as only 10 objects are allowed";}}

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have done.
I have two questions.

**1. Why doesn't it print any output?**

**2. How can I add a static member function that reclaims this memory?**

this is c++, thanks in advance.

Comment: the taks say you are supposed to implement a operator new not put everything in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Inside the constructor you call

```
 while (true){

        objects.push_back(new c());
        // <------------
```

And `new c()` calls the constructor, again, before there is any output. This again calls the constructor and that again pushes a new c to its `objects` which in turn again calls the constructor. There is an infinite recursion that never stops and the program flow never reaches the line marked with `// <------------`.

Comment: Oh okay so I should delete the new, right?

Comment: But the lab requires me to use a new operator, how can I accomodate that then?